# Can I use MySQL LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE if my rows don't have a 'name'?

Tags: mysql, xml

I have some XML that I am trying to load directly into a MySQL table. I am fairly comfortable with the idea of "ROWS IDENTIFIED BY", but I am stuck at the point where I want to save both the tag for the element and the text value of the element. I'll try to explain:

I created a MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE stat (
  Type VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  uID VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  value VARCHAR(40),
  created TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (Type, uID)
);
```

And now I want to load the xml which is in this format:

```
  <Employee uID="p17336">
    <Name>Joe Bloggs</Name>
    <Stat Type="first_name">Joe</Stat>
    <Stat Type="last_name">Bloggs</Stat>
    <Stat Type="birth_date">1985-07-26</Stat>
  </Employee>
```

What I want is for the 'Type' of each Stat element to populate the 'Type' column in MySQL (this is working fine) then the actual text of the element (for example 'Joe') to populate the 'value' column. How can I do this? Currently I am trying:

```
 LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:/dev/Sample/employees.xml'
 INTO TABLE stat
 ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Stat>';
```

And am getting all fields populated correctly except 'value', which is NULL. Any thoughts much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented under [`LOAD XML` Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-xml.html):

> This statement supports three different XML formats:
>
> - Column names as attributes and column values as attribute values:
>
>   ```
>   <row column1="value1" column2="value2" .../>
>   ```
> - Column names as tags and column values as the content of these tags:
>
>   ```
>   <row>
>     <column1>value1</column1>
>     <column2>value2</column2>
>   </row>
>   ```
> - Column names are the `name` attributes of `<field>` tags, and values are the contents of these tags:
>
>   ```
>   <row>
>     <field name='column1'>value1</field>
>     <field name='column2'>value2</field>
>   </row>
>   ```
>
>   This is the format used by other MySQL tools, such as [**mysqldump**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html).

Since your XML is in none of these supported formats, you must use some other tool to parse it.

Comment: I saw this on the mysql docs, I was hoping there would be some mapping trickery that I could do to get around it... I have decided to use hyperjaxb to create both jaxb mappings and hibernate entity mappings, and use those to load and store.