# MySQL XML Import LOAD XML INFILE Two Lines Same Name

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am using the following function to import data from an XML file:

```
// load data
$query = "LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '$file'
INTO TABLE product_stock_supplier
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>'";
$db->Execute($query);
```

Pretty basic, but it works fine. However, one of the XML files has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <products>
    <product>
      <eanno>7613152</eanno>
      <descr>eopren Tpu cale</descr>
      <modelno>200513</modelno>
      <gridvalue>222</gridvalue>
      <size>one size</size>
      <artno>3222</artno>
      <stock>20</stock>
      <date/>
      <price typ="retail" currency="GBP">463</price>
      <price typ="sales" currency="GBP">999</price>
      <image>no picture</image>
    </product>
</products>
</configuration>
```

I don't know how to extract the correct value from the two `<price>` rows? How do I tell the import function to identify `typ="retail"` and `typ="sales"`?

Thanks

Comment: If you have control over the XML before you import it, you could rename the `<price>` tags to match the correct columns e.g. `<retailprice>` and `<salesprice>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use MySQL LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE if my rows don't have a 'name'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483207/can-i-use-mysql-load-xml-local-infile-if-my-rows-dont-have-a-name)